# Button doesn't link to other page

Tags: html, button

On https://bm-translations.de/dolmetscher-franzoesisch-deutsch.php you can see the buttons are not working and I don't know why.

Structure is like that:

```
<button>
   <a href="https://bm-translations.de/#kontakt" target="_blank">Click here</a>
</button>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A `button` can't contain an `a`. The content model for a `button` forbids interactive content https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html here are some ways to make buttons behave like links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Comment: The big round red button?...it's working on Chrome

Comment: @Hackerman in chrome its working after a few seconds but its not working in firefox. This is quite strange. Propably I should style the <a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `a` tag is inside the `button`, the clickable padding area isn't part of the link. What you could do instead is invert the structure so that the `a` is the parent of the `button`.

```
<a href='#'>
  <button type='button'>
    Contact
  </button>
</a>
```

**Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/hh6eu4kL/

**Tested:**
Edge / Firefox / Chrome

Comment: easy an brilliant solution!